# Extracting Colour (Brush) information from MapInfo Workspace

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, workspace

I have some MapInfo Tables with an associated Workspace. I do not have access to MapInfo and wish to use the TAB files in QGIS (I also have the equivalent SHP files). The TAB/SHP files have polygons with associated attribute data. Colouring of the polygons was done in the Workspace (.WOR) file with the relevant part reproduced here:

```
Set Map
  CoordSys Earth Projection 3, 104, "m", 134, 0, -18, -36, 0, 0
  Center (-1052836.855,-3057718.85)
  Zoom 6700.860332 Units "km"
  Preserve Zoom Display Zoom
  XY Units "m" Distance Units "km" Area Units "sq m"
shade 2 with AGE_CLASS values 
  "" Brush (2,16711680,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Archaean" Brush (2,9800292,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Archaean to Proterozoic" Brush (2,13416577,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Cainozoic" Brush (2,16777168,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Mesozoic" Brush (2,5680257,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Mesozoic to Cainozoic" Brush (2,13696976,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Palaeozoic" Brush (2,10535167,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Palaeozoic to Cainozoic" Brush (2,13697023,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Palaeozoic to Mesozoic" Brush (2,13693695,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Proterozoic" Brush (2,16756912,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Proterozoic to Mesozoic" Brush (2,16752895,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) ,
  "Proterozoic to Palaeozoic" Brush (2,16765183,16777215) Pen (1,1,0) 
  default Brush (1,0,16777215) Pen (1,2,0)   # color 1 #
```

Is it possible to convert the Brush values to RGB?

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers are calculated by the formula ( red * 65536) + ( green * 256) + blue.

If you convert the number to hex the first two characters are the red value, the middle two are green and the right two are blue.

So for the "Archaean" brush  9800292 = 0x958A64 in hex (the 0x prefix denoting a hex number).  Omitting the 0x to focus just on the parts of the text we are interested in, leaves us with 958A64, 95 in decimal=149, 8A=138 and 64=100, giving RGB(149,138,100).

I used the excel functions `DEC2HEX` to convert the original number to hex, then split the result into three columns (two left characters, the two middle and two right) and then used `HEX2DEC` to convert each of the three parts back to decimal:

```
               Brush               | Mapinfo  |      RGB      
 ----------------------------------|----------|--------------- 
  Brush                            | 16711680 | (255,0,0)     
  Archaean Brush                   |  9800292 | (149,138,100) 
  Archaean to Proterozoic Brush    | 13416577 | (204,184,129) 
  Cainozoic Brush                  | 16777168 | (255,255,208) 
  Mesozoic Brush                   |  5680257 | (86,172,129)  
  Mesozoic to Cainozoic Brush      | 13696976 | (208,255,208) 
  Palaeozoic Brush                 | 10535167 | (160,192,255) 
  Palaeozoic to Cainozoic Brush    | 13697023 | (208,255,255) 
  Palaeozoic to Mesozoic Brush     | 13693695 | (208,242,255) 
  Proterozoic Brush                | 16756912 | (255,176,176) 
  Proterozoic to Mesozoic Brush    | 16752895 | (255,160,255) 
  Proterozoic to Palaeozoic Brush  | 16765183 | (255,208,255) 
  default Brush                    |        0 | (0,0,0)
```

The second number, the background colour, is the same for every brush and converts to RGB(255,255,255) white.